# Spring integration tcp factory performance

Tags: spring-integration

I have some performance problem with spring integration tcp factory.
my application have about 70 clients which trying to send data through tcp connection. i used below configuration for tcp server using spring integration but in server i receive data every 5 seconds. but when i implement tcp socket manually without using spring integration i receive about 5 connections in every second. any idea about my problem ? i really want to use spring integration but i don't know how can i increase my performance.

```
<int:poller id="defaultPoller" default="true" tast-executor="defaultTaskExecutor"  fixed-delay="500" />
<task:executor id="defaultTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-20" queue-capacity="50"/>

<bean id="CustomeSerializerDeserializer"
    class="CustomeSerializerDeserializer" />

<task:executor id="tcpFactoryTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-20"
    queue-capacity="20000" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpConnectionFactory"
    type="server" port="5423"
    single-use="false" so-timeout="5000" task-executor="tcpFactoryTaskExecutor"
    serializer="CustomeSerializerDeserializer" deserializer="CustomeSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="tcpInboundAdapter" channel="requestChannel" connection-factory="tcpConnectionFactory" />

<int:channel id="requestChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="50" /> 
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="responseChannel" ref="MessageHandler" method="parse" />

<bean id="MessageHandler"
    class="TCPMessageHandler" />

<int:channel id="responseChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="50" />
<int:channel /> 

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="tcpOutboundAdapter" channel="responseChannel" connection-factory="tcpConnectionFactory" />
```

**UPDATE1:** here is my custom serialize/deserializer class:

```
public class SerializerDeserializer extends AbstractByteArraySerializer{


   @Override
   public void serialize(byte[] object, OutputStream outputStream)
           throws IOException {
       if (object != null && object.length != 0) {
           outputStream.write(object);
           outputStream.flush();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
       int c = inputStream.read();
           if (c!=0){
               // 2 byte
               byte[] configMessage = BinaryUtil.readNByteArrayFromStream(inputStream, c)/*(inputStream , c)*/;

               return configMessage;
           }    
           int d = inputStream.read();
           if (d==0){
               // 253 byte

               byte[] dataMessage = BinaryUtil.readNByteArrayFromStream(inputStream,253);
               return dataMessage;
           }

           // 15 byte
           byte[] hanshakeMessage = BinaryUtil.readNByteArrayFromStream(inputStream,d);
           return hanshakeMessage;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a problem with your custom deserializer 5 seconds is suspicious since your timeout is also 5 seconds - show the code and explain the protocol.

If the deserializer doesn't receive a full message it will time out.

Also turn on TRACE level logging for `org.springframework.integration` to debug this - if you can't figure it out from the trace, post the log file somewhere like pastebin and we'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for you reply gary ... i edited my question and added  custom deserializer. about the timeout, i changed it to 10 seconds but it didn't change anything. also 5 seconds for reply is average time . sometimes it takes 3 seconds and some times more than 10 seconds. but most of the times it take about 5 seconds for each data to recieve.

Comment: Does TRACE logging shed any light?

Comment: One thing that i understood from Trace logging till now is that messages processing in sequence. when one message arrives no other message arrives until previous message replied to client and then next message arrives(with latency about 4 seconds )

Comment: When not using NIO, the downstream flow runs on the same thread that reads from the socket. However, since your `requestChannel` is a queue channel, that should immediately free up the thread to read the next message. That said, there's something wrong with your configuration - the service activator needs a `<poller/>` when consuming from a `QueueChannel`. Be sure to include the thread (`%t` with log4j) when debugging a multi-threaded application.

Comment: My Configuration is exactly like the one i put in the question. also i have a default poller for async channels. so i didn't get it. what is the problem in my configuration you think?

Comment: I don't know but there's obviously a disconnect somewhere. What you are describing makes no sense to me. There is nothing in the framework that would limit the throughput in the way you describe. If you haven't figured it out by (my) tomorrow morning I'll write a test case to prove it. It is not helpful when you don't show all your configuration such as your default poller.

Comment: I added my default poller in the question ... this is all of my configuration ... I appreciate your help... if you write a test case i can find out the difference and use your test case to find my problem. also i will continue searching about this problem in my logs.. thanks again

Comment: See [this project](https://github.com/garyrussell/sandbox/tree/master/so36667075) `Sent and received 1000 messages in 67 ms.`. It makes no difference whether `requestChannel` is a `QueueChannel` or not.

Comment: I checked your sample and it was pretty straightforward. i really can't find the problem in my case.maybe it's the clients problem. by the way thanks for your help and time